# Java sounds overlay

Tags: java, audio

i have a little pexeso game. Everytime somebody finds 2 of a kind it should play some predefined sound (each 2 cards have an unique one). The problem is that sometime it plays the sound it should + like 1 sec of another random(?) sound at the same time.

```
public void zahraj (URL u)
{

    AudioInputStream audio = null;          
    try {
        audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(u);

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    try {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        clip.open(audio);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    clip.start();


}
```

any ideas why is that so?

Comment: Is there any reason as to why not merge all the `try-catch` ones? If one fails now it will continue and try the next one.

Comment: you are right, but it does not solve my problem

Comment: Define random sound, random from your list of sounds or a random noise?

Comment: Oh, random sound from my list of sounds.

Comment: So? what does it look like?